# Subfigure with scalebox and latex file but keep the font size

Tags: subfloats

I am writing my dissertation right now and make all my figures with gnuplot and export all figures as vector graphics using the epslatex export. However, if I have two or four figures which should be combined, I am using the subfigure environment. To scale the graphics I have to use a scalebox. Thus, the fonts are scaled as well (which is obvious). The problem is, that I want to have the font scale in normal size, or any size I would like to have. One minimal example is given as follow (hope it works):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, ngerman]{scrreprt}
\newcommand{\figureSettings}{\tiny\centering}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h!]
\figureSettings
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.495\textwidth}
\scalebox{.6}{\input{Test.tex}}} 
\subcaption{}
\end{subfigure}
%
%
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.495\textwidth} 
\scalebox{.6}{\input{Test.tex}}} 
\subcaption{}
\end{subfigure}
% 
\\
%
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.495\textwidth}
\scalebox{.6}{\input{Test.tex}}} 
\subcaption{}
\end{subfigure}
%
%
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.495\textwidth}
\scalebox{.6}{\input{Test.tex}}} 
\subcaption{}
\end{subfigure}
%
%
%
%
\caption{Test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The image which is used here can be downloaded here ([tex-file](http://holzmann-cfd.de/forumCases/Test.tex) - [eps-file](http://holzmann-cfd.de/forumCases/Test.eps)). So my question is, is there a good way to have two figures (left-right) with correct font size but the images are scaled? I was expecting that epslatex is one of the best options I have using gnuplot.

Thanks you in advance and I hope I gave all information.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Probably you should use the `psfrag(x)` package to replace the labels.

Comment: Hi Bernhard, I will check the psfrag package. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Bernhard, the psfrag is not an option for me because I have a lot of figures in my dissertation. So I will not replace everything by the use of psfrag. However, thanks for the hint.